# distortion in making netlogo video

Tags: netlogo

I am making video of simulation on netlogo. The total time of video is around 30 minutes. When i play movie, it works fine for first couple of minutes[image], then the screen of movie starts distorting and after some times the black screen appears. [image] [image]I tried to making video on by setting different frame set (i.e. 6, 12 and 24). But every time i got the same behavior in movie. Any suggestion?

Comment: it's probably https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/issues/165

Comment: @SethTisue after reading the thread my understanding is i should convert the file into other codec as .mov is not good in handling big files. Am I correct?

Comment: There is a chance that if you convert the file to other codec, that will fix the corruption. If not, you might need to assemble the movie out of PNG files instead (using `export-view` or `export-interface`).